# In gradle, how can I generate the ivy.xml and pom.xml files?

Tags: maven, ivy, gradle

Currently, our gradle setup is geared to publish to certain maven repositories when a build is done. For a particular customer, I need to zip up the jars, license files, pom.xml, and ivy.xml files, and send it all in a zip. To do this, I just need to define an alternate location to publish it to. All the documentation on the gradle site seems aimed at writing one set of publishing rules, not an alternative set.

I was hoping to simply write a different task which would focus on building this customer-specific zip file. So far, I have it collecting all the jars (which includes source and runnable code) along with the license and notice file. But I haven't cracked the nut on defining a local ivy repository and a local maven repository that is only part of this alt task.

```
task alt {
    dependsOn subprojects*.tasks*.matching { task -> task.name == 'assemble' }

    subprojects.each{project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('sourceJar')) {
            evaluationDependsOn(project.name)
        }
    }

    File altDir = mkdir("$buildDir/alt")
    subprojects.each { project -> 
        if (project.hasProperty('sourceJar')) {
            // Extra the module name from the path of the sub-project
            String submodule = project.projectDir.absolutePath.split(File.separator).last()
            File subfolder = mkdir(altDir.absolutePath + "/${project.group}/${group}.${submodule}/$version")
            project.tasks.withType(Jar).each {archiveTask ->
                copy {
                    from archiveTask.archivePath
                    from("$rootDir") {
                        include 'license.txt'
                        include 'notice.txt'
                    }
                    into subfolder
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [gradle docs](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#newPom) that tells you how to generate the pom. Also if you are looking to install that file to your local repository you could use the mechanism described in this [blog entry](http://linkedjava.blogspot.com/2011/06/gradle-build-to-create-pom.html) .  Essentially all you have to do

```
configure(install.repositories.mavenInstaller) {
    pom.project {
        version '1.0'
        artifactId 'your.artifact.id'
        groupId 'your.group.id'
    }
}
```

It doesn't look like it possible at the moment to generate the ivy.xml through gradle, but once you have your pom file you could use ivy itself to generate the ivy file [described here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/convertpom.html).

Answer (score 0):

Section 64.5 of http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_ivy.html covers "Generating the Ivy module descriptor file without publishing".

The documentation is a little broken (eg inconsistent naming conventions). The following works for me:

```
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        aoeu(IvyPublication)
    }
}
```

This will generate a target `generateDescriptorFileForAoeuPublication`.